# django form based on model

Tags: django, forms

In http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example can anyone tell me the step by step process to map the AuthorForm and Bookform in my views.py and to render it in my template.

Answer (score -1):

The process is the same as with a regular Form (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), a ModelForm is basically just a shortcut and more DRY approach than creating a regular Form when that form's purpose is to create or edit a model instance.